# How can I exclude a string using a regular expression?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have this file named test:

```
http://edge.sharethis.com
http://edge.sharethis.com
https://timetosa.com
http://timetosa.com
https://webtest.es
holahttp.com
timetosa
```

I want a expression that excludes any line that contains timetosa.

This is not allowed : `cat test | grep -v timetosa`, because I want to use a pure regular expression in another program.

I know it has to do with `^` but cannot get to the right solution, to affect the ones which not include the string timetosa:

`cat test | sed 's/^[timetosa]//g'` and `cat test | sed 's/^(timetosa)//g'` without success.

Could anyone help me ¿?

Comment: Why `grep -v` do not allowed? What programm you want to use? What is the main goal of regex? If you need `sed` you can use `sed '/timetosa/! d'`

Comment: You can also look at this question asked earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: I am using this regular expression for ZAP proxy, so I cannot use linux commands there hehe

Comment: @Costas - I think you might have that `sed` backwards...

Comment: `timetosa` as a regexp would match anything that contains `timetosa` unless your regexps are implicitly anchored (as with `grep -x`) in which case you'll want `.*timetosa.*` (beware of the effect of locales though as `.` could fail to match bytes that are not part of valid characters).

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/timetosa/d' <test
```

...will do it. Alternatively:

```
sed -n '/timetosa/!p' <test
```

Still, though *(whether it's allowed or not)*:

```
grep -v timetosa <test
```

...is going to be the most performant solution of the three - and probably by a significant margin.

Thanks to @Sparhawk, I found my way to the [zaproxy documentation](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/HelpUiDialogsDialogs). Based on this:

- URL regexs

  - In the *Include in* *, *Exclude from* * panels and the *Logged in/out* indicators of the *Authentication* panel, you can enter regular expressions to define excluded URLs.

...and the following, I would guess you're trying to filter *Contexts*? According to the docs, you can do both include *and* exclude lists:

- [Exclude from context](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/HelpUiDialogsSessionContexts)

  - This allows you to manage the URLs which will be excluded from the context.
  - You only need to specify regexs for URLs that you do not want to include but which match one or more of the *include* regexes.

So you can exclude *some* of your previous inclusions.

Still, though, it may be the first bit of this is not *entirely* irrelevant - the docs also mention this in the *Add-ons* section:

- Invoke Applications

  - Other applications can be invoked passing in context information, such as the URL of the message selected.
  - So, for example, `nmap` could be invoked passing the site which you want it to scan.
  - Applications are configured using the [Options Applications](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/HelpAddonsInvokeOptions) screen.

Comment: I *think* they are asking for a generic regex, not a specific implementation in grep/sed, since they are using it in "ZAP proxy", whatever that is.

Comment: @Sparhawk - Ok - I'm gonna delete this - but where do you get the ZAP proxy thing? I don't see that anywhere... All I see is the `cat | sed` examples...

Comment: In the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183971/regex-select-exclude/183975?noredirect=1#comment306611_183971) to the question? Third one down.

Comment: No worries, and nice investigative work!

Answer (score 1):

[Regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) are closed under complementation, so for every regular expression, there exists a regular expression that matches exactly the inputs that the original regexp doesn't match.

However, in the worst case, the smallest regexp that matches the complement language has a length that is exponential in the length of the original regexp. So while the regexp is guaranteed to exist, it is not guaranteed to be simple. It can be [calculated algorithmically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452353/find-complement-of-regular-expression) if you really need it.

The `^` operator to anchor a regexp isn't relevant. You may be thinking of `^` in a character set, as in `[^a-z]` meaning “any one character that isn't a lowercase letter”. This is just part of the shortcut notation for character sets, it isn't helpful to complement a set of strings.

Some regular expression engines, such as perl's or the compatible nd  widely-used PCRE, support additional operators beyond the traditional ones including [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). A negative lookahead assertion provides a simple way to negate a regular expression without having to break it down into parts. Check the documentation of your software to see what kind of regular expressions it supports.

```
^(?!.*timetosa)
```

Or in `vim`:

```
^(.*timetosa)\@!
```

Most systems don't need regexp complementation because you can achieve the same effect by using a matching inversion flag (e.g. `grep -v`) or by ordering rules carefully in a first-match setting (if it matches `.*timetosa.*` then do nothing and stop matching rules; if it matches `.*` then do something).

Comment: Your long regexp fails on `ttimetosa`. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.unix.shell/dMA7D9wLe6E/wFmWk234hWYJ

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I did think it shouldn't be that small. I'm too tired to work it out and I don't have a regexp complementation implementation around.